# How to handle new tabs with the page object model with Playwright

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright, pageobjects, playwright-test

I want to know how to handle a tab or multiple tabs when using Page object model.

My test runs successfully if i don't use the page object model function to run it.
Basically when i click and navigate to the new tab i am using this on the normal test without the POM:

```
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
page.waitForEvent('popup'),
page.locator(button...).click();
]);
```

and then using the newPage as my new tab and it's working.

```
await newPage.locator(field).fill(testing);
...SNIP..
```

When using the POM I cant do that and I am not able to continue with the rest of the test, it doesnt recognise the new tab as i cant declare the new page in the POM.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

How can i implement the same logic using the POM ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. I also puzzled over how to do it.

```
constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.wait_for_event = page.waitForEvent('popup');
    this.your_button = page.locator(button...);
}

async f(){
    const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
        this.wait_for_event,
        this.your_button.click(),
    ]);
    await newPage.getByPlaceholder or another method('placeholder text').fill('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case something like this works:

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/LoginPage';
import { ProductsPage } from '../../pages/ProductsPage';

const purchasedProduct = 'Sauce Labs Backpack';

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
  await loginPage.goTo('inventory.html');
});

test('As a user I want to open a new tab and visit it', async ({
  page,
  context,
}) => {
  const productsPage = new ProductsPage(page);
  const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
    context.waitForEvent('page'),
    productsPage.openNewTabWithProduct(purchasedProduct),
  ]);
  await newPage.locator('text=Sauce Labs Onesie').click();
});
```

The crucial part is you have to put "context" instead of page as your test attribute. Then just use your newly created page